# How do we continue to be able to play in the array?

Tags: javascript

Making the audio player. The browser is not compatible tries to play the audio in the array using the embed tag. Continues to play and the next one is not to be played .Only one is played. I want to play the contents of the array in order.

```
var files = ['notibell_1.wav', 'notibell_2.wav', 'notibell_3.wav'];
var daudio = document.createElement('embed');
daudio.setAttribute('id', 'daudio');
daudio.height = "50";
daudio.width = "400";
daudio.controls = true;
daudio.autoplay = true;
daudio.type = "audio/wav";
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
  daudio.src = files[i];
}
bottom.appendChild(daudio);
```

Comment: Does it just play the last one in the array?

Comment: You can use the HTML5 `audio` elements instead of the old `embed`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating one single audio element, assign all the properties, and then set the source in a loop, overwriting it 2 times. Your loop should contain the whole element creation and appension:

```
var files = ['notibell_1.wav', 'notibell_2.wav', 'notibell_3.wav'];

for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    var daudio = document.createElement('embed');
    daudio.setAttribute('id', 'daudio');
    daudio.height = "50";
    daudio.width = "400";
    daudio.controls = true;
    daudio.autoplay = true;
    daudio.type = "audio/wav";
    daudio.src = files[i];
    bottom.appendChild(daudio);
}
```

Now all 3 audio files play at the same time. One easy way to avoid this would be to make a playlist-file. `.m3u` is an easy format. Make another file called `playlist.m3u`:

```
notibell_1.wav
notibell_2.wav
notibell_3.wav
```

Then just make one audio element, giving it the playlist as a source:

```
var daudio = document.createElement('embed');
daudio.setAttribute('id', 'daudio');
daudio.height = "50";
daudio.width = "400";
daudio.controls = true;
daudio.autoplay = true;
daudio.type = "audio/wav";
daudio.src = 'playlist.m3u';
bottom.appendChild(daudio);
```

Comment: Sorry, but the audio comes three. Why is this?

Comment: That is because this way you create 3 separate elements at the same time. I added a way to avoid this in my answer (untested, please tell me if it works)

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because you are updating `daudio.src` 3 times before they are able to play the sound. I would recommend that you use the HTML5 native audio elements and have your sounds ready at least in mp3 and ogg.

If you want to play the contents of the array in order, you can use the `ended` event listener to reproduce the next sound:

#### Javascript

```
var files = ['notibell_1.wav', 'notibell_2.wav', 'notibell_3.wav'];
var i = 0; 
audio = new Audio(files[0]);

//Let's add the ended event listener,
//change the source and play it.
audio.addEventListener('ended',function(){
    if(++i < files.lenght){
        audio.src = files[i];
        audio.pause();
        audio.load();
        audio.play();
    }
    else{
        audio.pause();
    }
});
```

I haven't tested, but you can get the idea